# Does a Seagate Desktop SSHD drive need to host the OS to optimize properly?

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, hybrid-storage

I've inherited a [Seagate Desktop SSHD 2TB](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/solid-state-hybrid/desktop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/). I plan to add it to my gaming desktop which already has a 128GB SSD that currently hosts the OS (Windows 8.1).

What I'm trying to determine is whether I should just add this new SSHD as a secondary drive and keep the OS on my SSD or install my OS onto the SSHD and use the SSD to host my most used applications and games?  I see that SSD will boot up a few seconds faster than an SSHD but if that renders the SSHD useless, than I'll reconfigure.

Ideas?

Comment: This is something you will have to decided.  SSD will be faster for obvious reasons.

Comment: SSHD bridges the gap between ordinary hard drives and SSD's, the SSD is the best option. Seagate has to market the SSHD in a way to spur sales, it is definitely slower in all respects to a SSD.

Answer (score 1):

sounds fine as a secondary drive. but it really depends on how you want to use it.

the files on the SSD will be faster, but if you have applicaations that make heavy repeated use of a small subset of their files putting those applications files on the SSHD makes sense.

moving the OS to the SSHG is not going tomake the OS faster, and unless you have a need for the space that the OS consumes on the SSD for some other purpose, leaving the OS on the SSD id probably the best way to go.